Preserve ignored untracked files across checkout
I picked up an external project, which I will be developing from now on.
As a failsafe measure, I made 2 branches:

One without a .gitignore, so as to not lose untracked files, called gitignoreless.
One with my guess at the right ignore pattern, called master.

Turns out I guessed wrong, and I need to track some of them.
I expected that checking out master after checking out gitignoreless would preserve the ignored files, but it's not so.
Are they now tracked just because they are tracked in a single branch?
Is there another reason that gets them deleted?
Is there a way to obtain this behaviour?
Most of the documentation and answers I found focus on the opposite: having the files deleted.

It sounds like you will be far better of ignoring some things locally using temporary commits.

@hlovdal

that answer's very useful, thank you.
i think rebase can actually do the trick!
if i branch the first commit into another one that lacks the .gitignore and commit everything, i should be able to rebase it whenever i want on top and immediately reset afterward (leaving working dir unchanged).

I'll try. Unorthodox but effective.

When you switch to a branch, Git makes sure that your working tree matches the content of the commit you're switching. Quoting an extract of Basic Branching of the Git Pro book:

when you switch branches, Git resets your working directory to look like it did the last time you committed on that branch. It adds, removes, and modifies files automatically to make sure your working copy is what the branch looked like on your last commit to it.

This means that:

Every tracked file in your working directory that is not present in the selected commit will be removed.

Every tracked file in the selected commit that is not present in your working directory will be added.

Every tracked file that is present in both your working directory and the selected commit will be updated to the version contained in the commit.


In your case, even though master had a .gitignore for some of the files on gitignoreless, once you switched to master those files had to be removed in order to match the content of master's head commit. This is because the files were already tracked on gitignoreless, and every tracked file in the working directory that is not contained in the selected commit is removed.
As already explained by @matt, .gitignore affects only files that are not already in the index. Therefore, you might want to consider having your .gitignore on all your branches, and build it in such a way to not show undesired files during the staging process. However, since some of the undesired files have already been tracked, you can "untrack" them with the --cached option of git rm. In your case, you could run:
# untrack the undesired files
git rm --cached <file1> <file2> ... <fileN>

# add the previous files as entries in your gitignore
echo <file1> >> .gitgnore
echo <file2> >> .gitgnore
...
echo <fileN> >> .gitgnore


yea, i tried the approach i mentionend as an alternative to this one. I planned to eventually delete the gitignoreless branch, so as to make the repo lighter. If i track them, then they'll forever be embedded in the repo. Even if i remove them with git rm. (right?)

It depends. Files will forever be part of the repo only if their blobs are linked by a tree object associated to a reachable commit. If not, Git gc will eventually get rid of them. In your case, if those files are only in the head commit of your branch, you could untrack them with git rm and amend the head commit. Alternatively, if they appear in more commits, you could perform an interactive rebase and remove them from every commit they're in.

However, this is just if you don't even want them in the object store. If they remain in your history and then at some point you untrack them is fine, unless they're really large files. When you perform git rm --cached you're just removing those files from the next commit. Previous commit will still have them.

The entire approach here (indeed, the very question title itself) seems to be based on a misapprehension, or a cascade of misapprehensions, about gitignore (and perhaps Git itself):

gitignore is not branch-based.

gitignore does not affect what happens during checkout.

gitignore has no effect on files that already exist in the repo (i.e. in the current HEAD); it affects only files that are not already in the index, and it affects only what happens when you say things like git status or git add.


So, if the goal is simply to develop a gitignore, then just develop it, i.e. change it incrementally, over time, as experience suggests.
How? Well, as I said, this is all about what git status means (and what git add . means). So think about your gitignore as you are making a commit by assembling files in the index. Every time you are about to make a commit, say git status to see what Git "knows" about the working tree in relation to the index (and the index in relation to the HEAD).

If you see a file being tracked in a way you don't like (e.g. it is listed as untracked and you want it to be both untracked and not mentioned any longer), list it in gitignore.

If you see a file has already been made part of the index and it shouldn't be, remove it from the index and list it in gitignore.

If files that you don't think should be checked in have already been checked in (i.e. not just in the index but in the HEAD), gitignore will have no effect on that. It would then be incumbent on you to delete such a file from the index and check that in as a commit, so that the file doesn't reappear in the index every time you switch to this branch.


Ultimately, though, don't expect gitignore to work some kind of magic. It is merely a time-saver, to help keep files from being checked into the repo that you do not want shared between developers (or with the public, if it's a public repo). Use it for what it's intended for and you'll be fine.

Thank you; it was clear from your reply already but i had no way to accept that as an answer.
Let me double check: i understand from what you say that the .gitignore is only meant as a faster way of excluding files from staging and committing, meaning it affects only the index. Right?

It doesn't even affect the index, though it can have an effect on what Git will automatically do to the index. Look at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore - first sentence, "A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore." In other words, this is just a way of saying, "Yes, Git, I know this file is untracked, and I want to keep it that way, and there is no need to nag me about it." It is a convenient way of getting Git to close its eyes to the existence of certain files in your working tree. It doesn't affect anything else.
